# How can I change the text from another view controller?

Tags: ios

I'm trying this

```
SignUpViewController *userEmail=[[SignUpViewController alloc] init];
userEmail.emailAddress.text=email;
```

but is not working.

Comment: Please provide more info. What's the context? Are you using nibs or storyboards? How are you calling this? Where are you calling this? What is "email"? What is "userEmail"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like emailAddress (assuming UITextfeild) is not allocated properly when you called

```
SignUpViewController *userEmail=[[SignUpViewController alloc] init];
```

So, it is nil at the point of init.

Better way to do would be, added one public property in SignUpViewController of NSString. Save the value in that property. Like Below

```
SignUpViewController *userEmail=[[SignUpViewController alloc] init];
userEmail.emailString=email;
```

in SignUpViewController.h file add

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *emailString;
```

in SignUpViewController.m file in view did load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

 //if you have not used nib or stroyboard init you textfield first
 emailAddress.text=emailString; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your emailAddress @property into the .h file of SignUpViewController (Assuming you have an IBOutlet property set from Storyboard or Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way of doing this is using a delegate to communicate between ViewControllers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/1397188) for a quick example of creating a protocol for the delegate method, setting the second ViewController as the first one's delegate and then calling that method.